# Functional Approach to join DataTables with dynamic number of columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, functional-programming

I have a project which will allow a user to add columns to a `DataTable` by left joining onto a `List<T>` (which will be converted to a `DataTable` via a helper method).  Current I've got this implementation which is working:

```
public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T t in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(t);
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return dt;
        }
        //for purposes of this demo, the first column in leftTable is always the 
        //column that's joined on
        public static DataTable JoinWithList<T>(this DataTable leftTable, IList<T> data,string propertyToAdd)
        {
            var rightTable = new DataTable();
            rightTable = data.ListToDataTable();
            var joiningColumn = leftTable.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            var columnIndex = 0;
            //find the index of type T whose property is the same as leftTable's

            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                if (prop.Name ==joiningColumn)
                {
                    columnIndex = i;
                }
            }
            var results = (from u in leftTable.AsEnumerable()
                          join s in rightTable.AsEnumerable()
                          on u[0] equals s[columnIndex] into ps
                          from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new
                          {
                              MembershipId = u[0],
                              UserName = u[1],
                              //some sort of function to iterate over and add columns here
                              Salary = p == null ? 0.01 : p[propertyToAdd] = p[propertyToAdd]
                          }).ToList().ListToDataTable();

            return results;
        }
```

I would like to be able to pass in a `List<string>` as the last parameter and inside the `select new` block have a variable number of columns appeneded to the new anonymous type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think functionally.
Try to isolate base cases and give recursive definitions that can be directly translated into your functional language of choice.

Let's see what the definition of `join` would be in pseudo-ML/F#:

```
_ join [] = []
[] join _ = []
H::T join L =
    append
        (L |> choose (match H) |> map (e -> (H, e)))
        (T join L)
```

You need to build the `match` function properly, to compare the right columns, and the function passed to `map` to build the new row (in my example just a tuple).

In C# (less elegant, with some inefficiencies but hopefully complete once `Match` and `Create` are filled in) a generic version might look like:

```
    public bool Match<A, B>(A a, B b)
    {
        // Match code
        return true;
    }

    public C Create<A, B, C>(A a, B b)
    {
        // Create new record
        return default(C);
    }

    public IList<C> Join<A, B, C>(IList<A> a, IList<B> b)
    {
        if(!a.Any() || !b.Any()) return new List<C>();
        var aHead = a[0];
        var bMatches = b.Where(bEl => Match(aHead, bEl));
        var newCs = bMatches.Select(bEl => Create<A, B, C>(aHead, bEl)).ToList();
        newCs.AddRange(Join<A, B, C>(a.Skip(1).ToList(), b));  // Recursive call
        return newCs;
    }
```

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with ML and F#.  For the time being, could you give some C# pseudo code for that ML?  That looks decently esoteric to me.